# Change of Roots of a Polynomial due to a Parameter

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial

$P(z)=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(z-Z_i)+tz^r$

where $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and $Z_i\in \mathbb{C}$ are fixed constants and $t$ is a real parameter. We want to estimate the behaviour of the roots for $t\rightarrow 0,t\in \mathbb{R}$.i.e. To write the roots of $P(z)$ as

$z_i=Z_i+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}C_jt^j$

and determine the $C_j$'s.

How can this be done?

Some background: A relevant application is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.03705.pdf Eq.7 and Appendix C. In this paper $n=4$ so we still can write out the analytic solutions and expand them directly, but I want to know whether this can be done for general n.

Comment: Assuming $Z_i \ne 0$, use the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) for the equation $t = - z^{-r} \prod_{i=1}^n (z - Z_i)$.

Comment: Oh, ok, it works, thank you.